# In search of a recursive function to replace all * with nested levels in combination with dotnotation of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For our project we're creating a mapper. We are doing this in combination with the Laravel dot notation helper. I am stuck on this for a moment now and I tried a lot of different recursive functions but none are giving me the expected result. It has to translate between a dotnotated array A to dotnotated array B.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Class ...

private function strpos_n($haystack, $needle, $nth = null) {
    $offset = 0;
    $allPositions = array();
    while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $offset   = $pos + 1;
        $allPositions[] = $pos;
    }
    return $nth === null ? $allPositions : ($allPositions[$nth] ?? '');
}

private function str_replace_n($search, $replace, $subject, $nth) {
    $found = preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($search).'/', $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    if (false !== $found && $found > $nth) {
        return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $matches[0][$nth][1], strlen($search));
    }
    return $subject;
}

...

$data = Arr::dot([
    'items' => [
        [
            'type' => 'product',
            'number' => 'TST_001',
            'quantity' => 5,
            'price' => 1.25,
            'variant' => [
                [
                    'color' => 'Navy Blue'
                ],
                [
                    'color' => 'Bright Red'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'type' => 'product',
            'number' => 'TST_002',
            'quantity' => 2,
            'price' => 8.34,
            'variant' => [
                [
                    'color' => 'Shady White'
                ],
                [
                    'color' => 'Dark Orange'
                ],
                [
                    'color' => 'Lemon Yellow'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]); // Hardcoded for testing

$map = [
    'items.*.type' => 'lines.*.type',
    'items.*.number' => 'lines.*.sku',
    'items.*.quantity' => 'lines.*.quantity',
    'items.*.price' => 'lines.*.price',
    'items.*.variant.*.color' => 'lines.*.colors.*.color',
]; // Hardcoded for testing
```

The function I'm searching for needs to search if the key exists in the data array, save as the mapper key and then 'level up' whenever the key doesn't exist go to the next entry and repeat (also for sub-levels).

What I got so far:

```php
foreach($map as $from => $to) {
    $hits = [];
    // Count occurrences
    $occurrences = substr_count($from, '*');
    // For each occurrence
    for($nth = 0; $nth < $occurrences; $nth++) {
        // Always start with 0 levels
        $fromKey = $from;
        $toKey = $to;

        // Save when key exists
        if(isset($data[$fromKey])) {
            $hits[$toKey] = $data[$fromKey];
        }

        // For each nested
        for($i = $nth; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $level = 0;
            $fromKey = $this->str_replace_n(($level == 0 ? '*' : $level - 1).'.', $level . '.', $fromKey, $i);
            $toKey = $this->str_replace_n(($level == 0 ? '*' : $level - 1).'.', $level . '.', $toKey, $i);

            // Save when key exists
            while(isset($data[$fromKey])) {
                $hits[$toKey] = $data[$fromKey];

                $level++;
                $fromKey = $this->str_replace_n(($level - 1).'.', $level . '.', $fromKey, $i);
                $toKey = $this->str_replace_n(($level - 1).'.', $level . '.', $toKey, $i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
{
    "lines.0.type": "product",
    "lines.1.type": "product",
    "lines.0.sku": "TST_001",
    "lines.1.sku": "TST_002",
    "lines.0.quantity": 5,
    "lines.1.quantity": 2,
    "lines.0.price": 1.25,
    "lines.1.price": 8.3399999999999999,
    "lines.0.colors.0.color": "Navy Blue",
    "lines.1.colors.0.color": "Shady White"
}
```

While I'm expecting:

```
{
    "lines.0.type": "product",
    "lines.1.type": "product",
    "lines.0.sku": "TST_001",
    "lines.1.sku": "TST_002",
    "lines.0.quantity": 5,
    "lines.1.quantity": 2,
    "lines.0.price": 1.25,
    "lines.1.price": 8.3399999999999999,
    "lines.0.colors.0.color": "Navy Blue",
    "lines.0.colors.1.color": "Bright Red",  // sublevel missing
    "lines.1.colors.0.color": "Shady White",
    "lines.1.colors.1.color": "Dark Orange",  // sublevel missing
    "lines.1.colors.2.color": "Lemon Yellow"  // sublevel missing
}
```

When providing a solution, please keep in mind that it has to be dynamic. Input/outputs do not always consist of only 1 sublevel, it could be infinite.

I've searched for any existing script, but couldn't find it only. Maybe I just don't know how this is called and am unable to find it, while it already exists for Laravel (out of the box)?  Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

For imports the order of the output array keys aren't any issue, since you search on the key. But for exporting data back to a customer it should be in the order as it was provided.

So: when the given data array (keys) is in a different order than the mapping array (keys). The output should be based on the mapping array (keys) order. For example if we 'shift' the data array into:

```php
$data = Arr::dot([
    'items' => [
        [
            'variant' => [
                [
                    'color' => 'Navy Blue'
                ],
                [
                    'color' => 'Bright Red'
                ]
            ],
            'quantity' => 5,
            'type' => 'product',
            'number' => 'TST_001',
            'price' => 1.25
        ],
        [
            'number' => 'TST_002',
            'quantity' => 2,
            'variant' => [
                [
                    'color' => 'Shady White'
                ],
                [
                    'color' => 'Dark Orange'
                ],
                [
                    'color' => 'Lemon Yellow'
                ]
            ],
            'price' => 8.34,
            'type' => 'product'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

And keep the mapping as is. The output should still be:

```php
Array
(
    [lines.0.type] => product
    [lines.0.sku] => TST_001
    [lines.0.quantity] => 5
    [lines.0.price] => 1.25
    [lines.0.colors.0.color] => Navy Blue
    [lines.0.colors.1.color] => Bright Red
    [lines.1.type] => product
    [lines.1.sku] => TST_002
    [lines.1.quantity] => 2
    [lines.1.price] => 8.34
    [lines.1.colors.0.color] => Shady White
    [lines.1.colors.1.color] => Dark Orange
    [lines.1.colors.2.color] => Lemon Yellow
)
```

Comment: The keys are different `'items.*.number' => 'lines.*.sku',` so mapping could get tricky for deeper levels.

Comment: vivek_23, I know. But the both keys always have the same nesting depth. If you get what I mean.

Comment: I can produce the mapping regardless of depth,but your expected result is actually a mapped one from `items` to `lines` and so on. Why map though?

Comment: vivek_23, we have multiple customers who all deliver different files. We need to map them to one layout so we can process. This way we could accept every file and only have to create a mapping array instead of a whole function per customer.

Answer (score 1):

First, we recursively flatten the array and then map to the standard result for simplicity and clean code.

**Step 1:**

To recursively generate the result, we first loop through each key and value pair and assign the dot notations accordingly.(Ignore this if `Arr::dot()` did this already and I did this since I have never used Laravel helpers so much).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$result = [];

function recursiveFlattening($data,$parent_key,&$result){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            recursiveFlattening($value,trim($parent_key . "." . $key,"."),$result);
        }else{
            $result[trim($parent_key . "." . $key,".")] = $value;
        }
    }
}

recursiveFlattening($data,'',$result);
```

**Step 2:**

- We need to map our flattened result with `$map` as you already defined.
- In the below code, we [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) the flattened key with the pattern in `$map`.
- If they both match, we [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) based on `.` and assign every bit (except the missing bit `*`, as it's already assigned in the key) with it's corresponding value and assign it as a new key to the final result.

**Pre-requisite:**

- It is always good to arrange the mapping pattern in descending order, matching the longest first and then moving to smaller patterns if not matched. Since we are doing a regex match, `.*` could perform a greedy match and override longer rules which had smaller rules as a prefix.
- Colliding patterns example(while regex matching):

  - `'items.*.variant.*.color' => 'lines.*.colors.*.color'`
  - `'items.*.variant.*.color.*.color' => 'lines.*.colors.*.color.*.false_positive_case'`
- Hence, we [uksort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) them in descending order to make sure we match correctly.

**Pattern arrangement Snippet:**

```
uksort($map,function($pattern_1,$pattern_2){
    return count(explode(".",$pattern_2)) - count(explode(".",$pattern_1));
});
```

**Mapping Snippet:**

```
<?php

 function mapToStandardFormat($result,$map){
    $mapped_result = [];

    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        $exploded_original_key = explode(".",$key);
        foreach($map as $pattern => $destination_pattern){
            if(preg_match("/^" . $pattern . "$/",$key) === 1){
                foreach(explode(".",$destination_pattern) as $pat_key => $pat_value){
                    if($pat_value !== '*'){
                        $exploded_original_key[$pat_key] = $pat_value;
                    }
                }

                $mapped_result[implode(".",$exploded_original_key)] = $value;       
                break; // break because it matched with current pattern itself
            }
        }
    }

    return $mapped_result;
}


print_r(mapToStandardFormat($result,$map));
```

**Full demo code:** https://3v4l.org/gunO5

Comment: vivek_23, thank you for the superb explaination. Very clear. The only thing we have to change is the results that aren't in the mapping don't have to be included in the result. So if we add a 'column' let's say: factory that isn't mapped it shouldn't be in the results.

Comment: @Brutus Thanks. Yes, I moved the `$mapped_result[implode(".",$exploded_original_key)] = $value;` above the break to ignore all those paths which don't match any pattern. Updated the demo link as well with an example.

Comment: @Brutus Also note that this works because your `map` values, for example `'items.*.type' => 'lines.*.type'` follows a regex syntatic sugar where the `.*` means match `0` or more characters.

Comment: @Brutus Also added sorting of `$map` due to overlapping issues while regex matching.

Comment: Epic! This works for all of our scripts. One question though, for import this works like a charm, since we search on key for reading in data. But for an export we array_flip the mapping array to return a format as the customer also provides. Is there a possibility to sort the output based on the keys the same as the mapping array?

Comment: @Brutus Great. Also, I am unable to understand about the export. Can you share an example in your post?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please feel free to read after **UPDATE**. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @Brutus I am a bit caught up. Will let you know soon.

Comment: I am also trying some things. Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: Hi Vivek, I was wondering if you've had some time to take an extra look at this? I can't seem to get it right.